# Powershell Object combobox

Tags: powershell, object, combobox

I'm filling a ComboBox by selecting objects.

```
$TrkList = $x.tracks | Where-Object { $_.properties.codec_id -eq "A_EAC3"} | Select-Object ID, codec, {$_.properties.language}
```

It works but I'd like a proper presentation.
For now, it shows like:

```
@{id=1; codec=AC-3/E-AC-3; $_.properties.language=eng}
@{id=1; codec=AC-3/E-AC-3; $_.properties.language=fre}
@{id=1; codec=AC-3/E-AC-3; $_.properties.language=jpn}
```

How could I show like:

```
ID 1: AC-3/E-AC-3 language:eng
ID 1: AC-3/E-AC-3 language:fre
ID 1: AC-3/E-AC-3 language:jpn
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since the only difference in those lines is the language property, might it be better to display just the language? If that's the case then you can use the `$comboBox.displayMember` property. Otherwise, I suggest parsing the string, then putting it in the combobox.

Comment: Thanks.
The DisplayMember property would be fine for me, but it's doesn't work with {$_.properties.language} (but it's fine if I use ID or codec).
Is there a specific way to do?

Comment: Well, I think the issue of why it works for id and codec is because you reference them specifically by name (your select-object statement). Where as `$_` is a reference to the current value in the pipe.

Comment: OK, it worked by renaming the object.

         Select-Object ID, codec, @{N='language'; E={$_.properties.language}}

Comment: Even better:

Select-Object @{N='MyDisplay'; E={'ID:' + $_.ID + ' - langue: ' + $_.properties.language + ' - Nombre de canaux: ' + $_.properties.audio_channels}}